# JavaScript метод sort

Tags: javascript

Нужно сортировать массив объектов по критерию (строке)

Хотел бы разобраться, что из себя представляет параметр(функция сортировки) для этого метода.

```
// Из документации я понял, что аргументы "a" и "b" это сравниваемые элементы
function func(a, b){ 
   // но не понимаю, что должна возвращать эта функция, и как реагирует на них метод sort?
}

[].sort(func);
```

На неком форуме нашел такой пример:

```
var k = [3, 5, 1, 7, 6, 7];
k.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}); // Сортирует по возрастанию
k.sort(function(a,b){return b-a;}); // Сортирует по убыванию
```

Как это работает?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Func - это коллбэк, то есть функция обратного вызова. Он нужен для того, чтобы функция sort "знала", как именно сравнивать сортируемые объекты между собой. Если вы когда-либо  пробовали написать какую-либо реализацию сортировки, то должны были видеть, что алгоритмы сортировки выполняют множество сравнений сотрируемых значений чтобы должным образом расположить их в результирующей последовательности. В случае с числами или строками JS в общем-то способен самостоятельно понять, какое значение больше/меньше/равно другому. Однако в случае со сложными типами этого не может знать никто кроме самого программиста. В этом случае на помощь приходит коллбэк - функция sort использует его при сравнении двух значений, скармливая ей в качестве аргументов два сравниваемых значения. В зависимости от возвращаемого результата sort может "понять", какое из значений больше. Скажем, у вас есть такой массив, который вы хотите отсортировать по полю Id:

```
var arr = [ { Id: 3, Name : "Вася" },{ Id: 1, Name : "Петя" },{ Id: 2, Name : "Витя" } ]
```

и такой коллбэк:

```
function (a, b)
{
     return a.Id - b.Id; 
}
```

и вы пытаетесь сравнивать с его помощью функции sort:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b)
{
     return a.Id - b.Id; 
});
```

в результате вы получите отсортированный по Id массив:

```
[ { Id: 1, Name : "Петя" },{ Id: 2, Name : "Витя" }, { Id: 3, Name : "Вася" } ]
```

Работает это так: если возвращаемое значение положительно (то естьa.Id больше, чем b.Id ), то функция sort "понимает", что объект a больше объекта b, если же значение отрицательно (a.Id меньше b.Id), то объект b меньше объекта a и следовательно объект и должен занимать в отсортированной последовательности более высокую позицию. В случае, если возвращаемое значение равно нулю, то объекты равны.

В основном функция сортировки нужна как раз для сортировки "сложных" типов, в этих случаях JavaScript не способен определить алгоритм сравнения объектов. Однако никто не мешает использовать ее и для простых типов. Это может быть полезно например если вы хотите сортировать последовательность по какому-то иному принципу

Comment: А что делать, если есть сортировка по дате и одна или несколько записей `undefined`?

Comment: @Максим это уже вы сами решаете. Можете, например, предварительно отсортировать все записи, у которых дата = `undefined`.